# php image retrieve doesn't show mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an issue rendering stored images from phpmyadmin database.

I have two files, first one is  image.php ,which is suppose to retrieve the images from database :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password");
if(!$conn)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysqli_select_db("imagestore");
if(!$db)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
$ano = $_GET['ano'];
$q = "SELECT aphoto,aphototype FROM animaldata where ano='$ano'";
$r = mysqli_query("$q",$conn);
if($r)
{

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$type = "Content-type: ".$row['aphototype'];
header($type);

readfile($ano);
echo mysql_real_escape_string.$row['aphoto'];
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}

?>
```

and  show.php , which is suppose to show the retrieved image :

```
 <?php
//show information
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include "connect.php";


$q = "SELECT * FROM animaldata";
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
if($r)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{
//header("Content-type: text/html");
echo "</br>";
echo $row['aname'];
echo "</br>";
echo $row['adetails'];
echo "</br>";

//$type = "Content-type: ".$row['aphototype'];
//header($type);
echo "<img src=image.php?ano=".$row['ano']." width=300 height=100/>";


}
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

When I try show.php i get this result:

[image]

I would be very grateful for any help, because i tried many different codes but i could not find the solution and still getting the same result.

Thank you.

Comment: in your first file it should be `$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);` instead of `$r = mysqli_query("$q",$conn);`

Comment: Also in some place you are using mysql fuctions and in some places mysqli please fix the same. mysqli_real_escape_string is a function you need to change that part also

Comment: for reference, storing images as raw encoded data in a SQL db is very inefficient, it is far faster both from the database and image retrieval and output point of view, and cleaner, to store the images in the filesystem and then to just save the filepath into the database.

Comment: Thanks, but can I keep this type of storing images if I want to publish my website, and store users images in my server ?..do you have a reference for that....thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the `readfile`line as it is not needed and also the `mysqli_real_escape_string` from the line below. Otherwise this looks like it could work, but without knowing how you stored the images I can't know for sure. For example, if you stored them base64 encoded then you'd need to echo the the base64 decoded string.